# Bubbling up an exception: Java

Tags: java, exception

So I have a method where if an exception occurs, I want to retry the operation within the method. If the exception happens a second time, I want the exception be caught where the method is called by another class. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
    public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessTokenWithRefreshToken  (String refreshToken) throws OAuth2AccessTokenErrorResponse, IOException, InterruptedException ,ExecutionException  {
    try {
        System.out.println("trying for the first time");
        OAuth2AccessToken mAccessToken = mOAuthService.refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
        return mAccessToken;
     catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        try {
            System.out.println("trying for the second time");
            OAuth2AccessToken mAccessToken = mOAuthService.refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
        }  catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
            throw e2;
        }
    }
    return mAccessToken;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a loop, in order not to repeat yourself:

```
public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessTokenWithRefreshToken  (String refreshToken) throws OAuth2AccessTokenErrorResponse, IOException, InterruptedException ,ExecutionException {
    int maxAttempts = 2;
    int attempt = 0;
    while (attempt < maxAttempts) {
        try {
            return mOAuthService.refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            attempt++;
            if (attempt >= maxAttempts) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    return null; // or throw an exception - should never be reached
}
```